# java urlconnection doesnt throw sockettimeoutexception

Tags: java, networking, io

I consistently encounter java httpurlconnections, which, even with a `setReadTimeOut()`, will not throw a sockettimeoutexception when they should, and it is consistently associated with an eventual (after hanging for 2-3 minutes) Premature EOF Exception. I read in a few blogs that this may have to do with reading in using BufferedReader's readLine method, 
    String x = ""; while((x=bufferedReader.readLine())!=null){}

at the end of a file if there is no new line character at the end of an inputstream. This does not make sense, why doesn't java's setTimeOut function correctly?

```
       URL url=new URL("");
      c=(HttpURLConnection)url.openConnection();
      c.setReadTimeout(17000);
      BufferedReader b = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(c.getInputStream()));
      String s;

      while((s=b.readLine())!=null)
      {     
          } ect.






    java.io.IOException: Premature EOF
at sun.net.www.http.ChunkedInputStream.readAheadBlocking(Unknown Source)
at sun.net.www.http.ChunkedInputStream.readAhead(Unknown Source)
at sun.net.www.http.ChunkedInputStream.read(Unknown Source)
at java.io.FilterInputStream.read(Unknown Source)
at sun.net.www.protocol.http.HttpURLConnection$HttpInputStream.read(Unknown Source)
at sun.nio.cs.StreamDecoder.readBytes(Unknown Source)
at sun.nio.cs.StreamDecoder.implRead(Unknown Source)
at sun.nio.cs.StreamDecoder.read(Unknown Source)
at java.io.InputStreamReader.read(Unknown Source)
at java.io.BufferedReader.fill(Unknown Source)
at java.io.BufferedReader.readLine(Unknown Source)
at java.io.BufferedReader.readLine(Unknown Source)
```

Here are the Response Headers (with exact cookie info truncated):

```
     [HTTP/1.1 200 OK]
     p3p ["",""]
     x-frame-options [SAMEORIGIN]
     Date [Tue, 08 May 2012 15:01:40 GMT]
     Vary [Accept-Encoding,User-Agent]
     Transfer-Encoding [chunked]
     Set-cookie [""=""; path=/; domain=""; expires=Tue, 01-Jan-2036 08:00:01 GMT]
     Content-Type [text/html; charset=ISO-8859-1]
     Server [Server]
```

Comment: Can you post the code you are using to create your url connection and the code to read it?

Comment: What is your final goal? Is it to have one big text file? Could you switch this from reading liny by line to byte by byte?

Comment: yes i could but i don't like it that java's setReadTimeout doesn't work.

Comment: Can you add this after BufferedReader `System.out.println(c.getHeaderFields());`. I am attempting to see if I can create a server that will reproduce this issue but have not been able to.

Comment: will try this for the next time my program catches the exception. it is hard to reproduce the error since it might come from the server's response.

Comment: yeah I understand. It definitely is a weird one. I've tested the readTimeout and it does work (at least for me). So we will have to find out what your unique case is.

Comment: This looks like a data problem. What is being *sent?* and are you sure it is correct?

Comment: The headers for GET request are set as (not post): h.setRequestProperty("Accept-Language","en-US,en;q=0.8");
      h.setRequestProperty("Accept-Charset","ISO-8859-1,utf-8;q=0.7,*;q=0.3");h.setRequestProperty("Connection","keep-alive");h.setRequestProperty("Cache-Control","max-age=0");    regardless of headers the timeout should stop the connection and it doesnt

Comment: A GET request doesn't have a body. Why are you reading one?

Comment: i'm not. i'm sending that request. what is being sent from the server is a webpage, not my server.

Comment: I will ask again. What data is being sent *that you are trying to read with the `readLine()` calls?*

Answer (score 0):

See the documentation for [setReadTimeout](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/1.5.0/docs/api/java/net/URLConnection.html#setReadTimeout%28int%29):

```
Some non-standard implementation of this method ignores the specified timeout.
```

If you don't think that's the issue, set the timeout to a very low number like 1 and check. You should get a `java.net.SocketTimeoutException` exception.

Comment: I read that. But you can check the readtimeout to see if it is actually there, and it is 100 percent of the time.

Comment: What happens if you set the value to 2?

Comment: @user845279 since he is using (I'm assuming) an Http or Https connection it will rely on suns default sun.net.www.packges which do follow readTimeout.

Comment: it throws a sockettimeout exception. It almost always works, except when it encounters a premature eof exception which my guess has ssomething to do with an input stream not having a new line character at the end.

Comment: @SamAdams what happens if you just ignore the error? This may not actually be something that is your fault. The server very likely could be shutting down the stream prematurely.

Comment: its two minutes of hanging, thats the only problem. i know its the servers fault, but its wasting my programs performance